# Jacob: Call to VBA failed

Tags: java, vba, excel, jacob

I have a Excel VBA written and trying to call it from java (using Jacob) as below:

```
public void PnlCubeExcelMacroCallAndRefresh() {
  ComThread.InitSTA();
  File file=new File("C:\\Users\\Pnl_Cube_Template.xlsm");
 // String macroName="Retrieve()";
   String macroName="Retrieve()";

    final ActiveXComponent excel = new ActiveXComponent("Excel.Application");

    try {
        // This will open the excel if the property is set to true
        excel.setProperty("Visible", new Variant(true));
        final Dispatch workbooks = excel.getProperty("Workbooks").getDispatch();
        //String    eventSink = null ;
        int id = Dispatch.get(workbooks, "Count").getInt();
        System.out.println("le nbre" + id);
        Dispatch.call(workbooks, "Add");
        Dispatch workBook = Dispatch.call(workbooks, "Open", file.getAbsolutePath()).toDispatch();

        Variant V1 = new Variant( file.getName() + macroName);
        // Calls the macro
        final Variant result = Dispatch.call(excel, "Run", V1);

        // Saves and closes
        //Dispatch.call(workBook, "Save");

        com.jacob.com.Variant f = new com.jacob.com.Variant(true);
        //  Dispatch.call(workBook, "Close", f);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        excel.invoke("Quit", new Variant[0]);
        ComThread.Release();
    }
}
```

But when I run this below error is encountered:

com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Invoke of: Run
Source: Microsoft Excel
Description: Cannot run the macro 'Pnl_Cube_Template.xlsmRetrieve'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

I have tried changing the trust center settings as well, still same issue.

[image]

Comment: Well, do you have a macro in the workbook called `Pnl_Cube_Template.xlsmRetrieve`?

Comment: @immibis: Yes.. I do, added a screen shot of it.

Comment: I see a macro called `Retrieve`, not a macro called `Pnl_Cube_Template.xlsmRetrieve`.

Comment: @Vinod are you quite sure that name is correct? Maybe try just "Retrieve".

Comment: @immibis: I have changed the Variant to just the macro name, now its running till 3rd line of the macro and then I get a run-time error:
Cannot run the macro 'EssMenuRetrieve'

Comment: Am able to run the macro via excel, when I call the macro via above method its throwing the run time error.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code

```
Variant V1 = new Variant( file.getName() + "!"+macroName);
```

and

```
macroName = "Retrieve"
```

without the parentheses